# Spring - @Deletemapping

Tags: html, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I need some input thanks :)   (Spring Boot 2.0)

EDIT: This method does work with @Getmapping - but when I replace it with @Deletemapping it gives me "error 405".

I have made this controller:

```
//Delete controller
        @DeleteMapping("delete/venue/{id}")
        public String deleteVenue(@PathVariable("id") Integer id)
        {

            log.info("deleteVenue action called...");

            venueService.removeVenue(id);

            log.info("deleteVenue action ended...");

            return "redirect:/"+readvenue;

        }
```

Html part:

```
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" th:href="${'delete/venue/' + venue.venueId}"></a>
```

I get this error:

---

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Dec 14 12:52:35 CET 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).

### Request method 'GET' not supported

My teacher informed me that I need an anchor tag in the HTML - Have tried different things non-works.  - Maybe someone out there has the solution.

Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Clicking a link on an html page results in an http GET request. That's why your `@GetMapping` works.

When you change the controller mapping to `@DeleteMapping` you're still sending an http GET when you're clicking on the link and you're getting an error that GET is not allowed for this mapping, only DELETE.

You have to also change your client side to send a DELETE request. You can attach some javascript, on the click event of the link, that executes a DELETE request.